Trouble with DragGesture and Snapping 3D Model to Surface in VisionOS using ARKit
I’ve been working on an app for Vision Pro for about a month with decent progress so far. The goal is to have an MVP ready in about 10 days (I know, tight deadline). However, I’m currently struggling with enabling the user to move a 3D model in ImmersiveSpace using DragGesture, and then snapping it to the nearest surface (wall, floor, ceiling, or table). While the code compiles and runs, the model doesn’t appear, and both the dragging and snapping functionalities fail to work.
For context, I’m relatively new to Swift and VisionOS, and I’ve been relying on Cursor (AI coding companion) for assistance. Apologies in advance if the code isn’t perfectly structured.
Below is the code for ImmersiveView.swift. I’d appreciate any help in spotting the issue.
import SwiftUI
import RealityKit
import RealityKitContent

struct ImmersiveView: View {
    @Environment(AppModel.self) private var appModel
    @State private var anchor: AnchorEntity?
    @State private var draggedEntity: Entity?
    @State private var initialEntityPosition: SIMD3<Float>?

    var body: some View {
        RealityView { content in
            print("ImmersiveView: Setting up RealityView content")
            let newAnchor = AnchorEntity()
            content.add(newAnchor)
            anchor = newAnchor
            
            // Load the toy car model
            Task {
                await loadToyCarModel()
            }
        } update: { content in
            if let carEntity = appModel.carEntity {
                carEntity.position = appModel.carPosition
            }
        }
        .gesture(dragGesture)
        .task {
            await startCarPositionUpdateTask()
        }
    }
    
    private func loadToyCarModel() async {
        do {
            guard let toyCarEntity = try? await Entity(named: "toyCar", in: realityKitContentBundle) else {
                print("ImmersiveView: Failed to load toyCar entity")
                return
            }
            
            print("ImmersiveView: Successfully loaded toyCar entity")
            
            let toyCarModel: ModelEntity
            if let model = toyCarEntity as? ModelEntity {
                toyCarModel = model
                print("ImmersiveView: toyCar entity is already a ModelEntity")
            } else if let firstChild = toyCarEntity.children.first as? ModelEntity {
                toyCarModel = firstChild
                print("ImmersiveView: Extracted ModelEntity from toyCar's first child")
            } else {
                print("ImmersiveView: Unable to find a suitable ModelEntity in the loaded toyCar entity")
                return
            }
            
            // Configure the car entity
            toyCarModel.generateCollisionShapes(recursive: true)
            toyCarModel.components[CollisionComponent.self] = CollisionComponent(
                shapes: toyCarModel.collision?.shapes ?? [],
                mode: .trigger,
                filter: .sensor
            )
            
            toyCarModel.position = [0, 0, -2]
            toyCarModel.scale = [1, 1, 1]  // Adjust scale if needed
            
            // Add the car to the anchor
            anchor?.addChild(toyCarModel)
            appModel.carEntity = toyCarModel
            
            print("ImmersiveView: Added toy car model to content")
        } catch {
            print("ImmersiveView: Error loading toy car model: \(error)")
        }
    }
    
    private func startCarPositionUpdateTask() async {
        while true {
            appModel.updateCarPosition()
            try? await Task.sleep(for: .milliseconds(100))
        }
    }
    
    private var dragGesture: some Gesture {
        DragGesture()
            .targetedToAnyEntity()
            .onChanged { value in
                print("ImmersiveView: Drag gesture detected - onChanged")
                guard let carEntity = appModel.carEntity,
                      value.entity == carEntity else { return }
                
                if draggedEntity == nil {
                    draggedEntity = carEntity
                    initialEntityPosition = carEntity.position
                }
                
                guard let initialPosition = initialEntityPosition else { return }
                
                let translation = value.translation3D
                let newPosition = initialPosition + SIMD3<Float>(translation)
                
                appModel.carPosition = newPosition
                print("ImmersiveView: Dragging car. New position: \(newPosition)")
            }
            .onEnded { _ in
                print("ImmersiveView: Drag gesture detected - onEnded")
                draggedEntity = nil
                initialEntityPosition = nil
            }
    }
}

#Preview(immersionStyle: .mixed) {
    ImmersiveView()
        .environment(AppModel())
}



Apple provides an easy GestureComponent in their sample code for dragging, as far as snapping you would have to include PlaneDetection and search between the planes you have found to modify the onEnded position to the equivalent on the plane.

Thanks for taking the time to reply. Despite widely exploring Apple's documentation on VisionOS I totally missed Gesture Component which is definitely a must-implement.
I'm struggling with some issues tho. I've copied the additional files from the sample code to my project and GestureComponent.swift returns several errors that Xcode makes you fix by adding @MainActor at the beginning. Any chance you experienced the same?
FYI. I'm coding on Xcode 16 (beta) with Swift 6 and testing on Vision Pro with VisionOS 2.0 (beta).

I haven’t migrated this code but If MainActor fixes it that should be ok for GestureComponent. Don’t get too liberal with MainActor because it will get clogged. https://developer.apple.com/wwdc24/10169

MainActor indeed fixed the issues in the GestureComponent. And, Apple Documentation makes it easy enough to setup gestures on the 3D model. It is worth pointing out that Gesture Component, Input Target and Collision must be added to the 3D model itself in Reality Composer Pro.

You can do it programmatically too
